# Angular2 v6 - ng-snotify

Tags: angular

i have a problem creating async Notification.
What i want to do:

My Component.ts:

Clicking on button runs a function:

```
onSubmit() {

    // when function is used show notification - async

    this.User.someFunction(this.form).subscribe(
      data => this.handleResponse(data),
      error => this.handleError(error.error.error)
    );
  }

handleError(error){
  // Change async into error notification with some data
}
handleResponse(data){
  // Change async into success notification with some data
}
```

Temporarily i have used material spinner which is displayed after function runs and it hides after there's response from server with error or success.